# How to make AJAX responses fade into view using jQuery in an MVC3 View?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, fade

How can I give a fade in effect for a `<p>` element in my website?

For example, here I'm using Ajax to fetch the current server time. They are brought up into view abruptly and I was wondering if I could make that appearance be smoother. Fade it in, if possible.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".newstatus").fadeIn();
    });
</script>

@Ajax.ActionLink("Update Status", "GetStatus", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "status", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter })
```

And in my Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetStatus()
{
    return Content("<p class=\"newstatus\">Status OK - " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + ".</p>");
}
```

Any suggestions on how to approach this particular problem? I'd like to use jQuery if possible.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$("#elementid").fadeIn();

this will fade in the elementid element

Comment: make sure it is hidden to start with or you may get an ugly flash of it before it fades in. You may want to use `$("#elementid").hide().fadeIn();` or add the html attribute `style="display:none;"`

Comment: @regality: Please see edit, it's not fading in - but just popping up as before. Any ideas?

Comment: With the code you have up there it will just fade in at page load, and it's probably empty. Don't run the fade in code until after the content is loaded into the DOM and hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) in the callback function of your ajax request. You'll have to give a code sample of your Ajax request if you want the exact code for it.

Comment: Let me edit my question, I'm afraid I don't understand what a callback is.

Comment: For example, in the link you shared, the elements are already in the page. I'm using AJAX to fetch and append new HTML elements, is that the reason why the script isn't working as intended?

Comment: Ah, you're using `.net` or something. I'm not sure what Javascript that will actually output, so I can't help more than I have, sorry.

Comment: @Sergio Tapia, no that's not the problem, an Ajax callback is a function that is called when the Ajax is complete, so at that point you can fadeIn() the elements. I don't know `.net` though so I'm not sure how much help I an be. I know you want to use something in AjaxOptions, probably OnSuccess

Answer (score -1):

use selecter name and call built-in function fadeIn(). for example

$("#element_id").fadeIn()